# Python - Tensorflow: How to map a function to a dataset properly

Tags: python, function, dictionary, tensorflow, dataset

I'm working through a machine learning curriculum and I have some trouble solving an issue with the given code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

(data), info = tfds.load("iris", with_info=True, split="train")
print(info.splits)

data = data.shuffle(150)
train_data = data.take(120)
test_data = data.skip(120)

def preprocess(dataset):
    
    def _preprocess_img(image, label):
        label = tf.one_hot(label, depth=3)
        return image, label
            
    dataset = dataset.map(_preprocess_img)
    return dataset.batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

train_data = preprocess(train_data)
test_data = preprocess(test_data)
```

This is just a code snippet but it should cover the problem area here. I get the error message: **TypeError: outer_factory..inner_factory..tf___preprocess_img() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label'**

I wasn't able to solve it, has anyone an idea what went wrong here? I mean yes, the function expects the label argument, but with other examples I saw it seems to work. But I wonder if maybe the unpacking of the dataset doesn't work as expected?

What I tried was changing the function that was going to be mapped, I had a look on the elements of the dataset but it really didn't help getting me the right insight. I was also looking for other examples but I can't see anything wrong with this particular code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With default parameters, `tfds.load` returns a dictionary. Look:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

data = tfds.load("iris", split="train")

next(iter(data))
```

```
{
    'features': <tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=float32, 
        numpy=array([5.1, 3.4, 1.5, 0.2], dtype=float32)>, 
    'label': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=0>
}
```

This is one object only, and so your preprocessing function is expecting two. You need to either use the dictionary format in your preprocessing function, or get your data in another format. To get it as a `tuple` and be able to use your function as is, use the `as_supervised=True` argument in `tfds.load`.

Simplified example working (without changing your preprocessing function:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

data = tfds.load("iris", split="train", as_supervised=True) 


def preprocess(dataset):
    def _preprocess_img(image, label):
        label = tf.one_hot(label, depth=3)
        return image, label

    dataset = dataset.map(_preprocess_img)
    return dataset.batch(4)


train_data = preprocess(data)

print(next(iter(train_data)))
```

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[5.1, 3.4, 1.5, 0.2],
       [7.7, 3. , 6.1, 2.3],
       [5.7, 2.8, 4.5, 1.3],
       [6.8, 3.2, 5.9, 2.3]], dtype=float32)>, 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)>)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Import the modules

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
```

## Load the Iris dataset and split it into training and testing sets

```
(train_data, test_data), info = tfds.load("iris", with_info=True, split=["train[:120]", "train[120:]"], as_supervised=True)
```

## Define a preprocessing function

```
def preprocess(image, label):
    # Perform one-hot encoding for the labels
    label = tf.one_hot(label, depth=3)
    return image, label
```

## Map the preprocessing function to the datasets and batch them

```
train_data = train_data.map(preprocess).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
test_data = test_data.map(preprocess).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

## Optionally, you can verify the splits and the first batch of data

```
print("Training data splits:", train_data.cardinality())
print("Testing data splits:", test_data.cardinality())
```

## Iterate over the data batches (for demonstration)

```
for batch in train_data.take(1):
    images, labels = batch
    print("Batch shape:", images.shape)
```